# Too many errors on log

Tags: php, errors

My shared hosting go to 100% CPU

i check error_log and appears too many errors

```
[23-Aug-2022 22:15:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/post.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-settings.php on line 194
[23-Aug-2022 22:15:06 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/general-template.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-settings.php on line 190
[23-Aug-2022 22:15:06 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/class-wp-theme-json.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-settings.php on line 174
[23-Aug-2022 22:15:06 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/taxonomy.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-settings.php on line 221
[23-Aug-2022 22:15:06 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/post.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-settings.php on line 194
[23-Aug-2022 22:15:10 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-settings.php on line 168
[23-Aug-2022 22:15:10 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-users-controller.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-settings.php on line 268
[23-Aug-2022 22:15:10 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-attachments-controller.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-settings.php on line 257
[23-Aug-2022 22:15:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/media.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-settings.php on line 233
[23-Aug-2022 22:15:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/sodium_compat/autoload.php on line 45
[23-Aug-2022 22:15:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/user.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-settings.php on line 185
[23-Aug-2022 22:15:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/sodium_compat/autoload.php on line 45
[23-Aug-2022 22:15:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/class-wp-theme-json.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-settings.php on line 174
[23-Aug-2022 22:15:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/class-wp-theme-json.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-settings.php on line 174
[23-Aug-2022 22:15:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/sodium_compat/autoload.php on line 45
[23-Aug-2022 22:15:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/wp-includes/sodium_compat/autoload.php on line 45
```

Comment: Those errors look to me to be a file permissions/ownership issue - PHP is failing to load the majority of core WordPress files

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/